# Как разбить дату 20.11.2016 по 20.01.2017?

Tags: javascript

Нужно что бы эти даты разбились на составляющие то есть
если 20.11.2016 по 20.01.2017
то '20.11.2016' , '21.11.2016' , '22.11.2016'....и так до '19.01.2017' , '20.01.2017'

в виде js

Пробовал

```
var d = new Date(2016, 10, 20);
var end = new Date(2017, 01, 20);
var dates = [];
while (d <= end) {
  dates.push(d.toLocaleDateString());
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}
```

но не получается. При `new Date(2017, 01, 20)` оно показывает не как первый меся а, как второй

Comment: Что вы пробовали? Что не получилось?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский var d = new Date(2016, 10, 20);
var end = new Date(2017, 01, 20);
var dates = [];
while (d <= end) {
  dates.push(d.toLocaleDateString());
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не получается вывести как в описании у меня

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понимаете  new Date(2017, 01, 20) оно показывает не как первый меся а как второй

Comment: parseInt() можно использовать

Comment: @kursof отсчет месяцев идет с 0, а не 1. поэтому 0-январь, 1-февраль и т.д.

Comment: @Alex я понимаю как исправить то так что бы писать не в формате  new Date(2017, 0, 20) а вот так  new Date(2017.01.20)

Comment: @kursof а зачем? Вам же нужно получить массив дат, т.е. Вам нужно чтобы в массиве было не 20.12.2016, а 20.11.2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var start = '20.11.2016', end = '20.01.2017';
var stArr = start.split('.'), endArr = end.split('.');
var daysArray = [];

var date = new Date(stArr[2], parseInt(stArr[1]) - 1, parseInt(stArr[0]));

while (true) {  
  var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();  
    
  daysArray.push(("0" + day).slice(-2) + '.' + ("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + year);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  
  if (day == endArr[0] && month == endArr[1] - 1 && year == endArr[2]) {        
    break;
  }      
}

console.log(daysArray);
```

здесь

`("0" + day).slice(-2)` - добавляет ведущий ноль, если в дне число от 1 до 9

`("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2)` - добавляет ведущий ноль, если в месяце число от 1 до 9, а также добавляет 1, т.к. отсчет месяцев ведется с нуля

в строке `var date = new Date(stArr[2], parseInt(stArr[1]) - 1, parseInt(stArr[0]));` делается `parseInt` если в номере дня или месяца имеется ведущий ноль. Таким образом он обрежется. Плюс в качестве месяца указан `parseInt(stArr[1]) - 1`, т.к. номер месяца отсчитывается с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var start = new Date(2016, 10, 20),
  end = new Date(2017, 01, 20),
  between = [],
  year, month, day;

while (start <= end) {
  var d = (!d) ? start.getDate() : 1;
  while (true) {
    if (d != new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth() - 1, d).getDate() ||
      (start.getFullYear() == end.getFullYear() && start.getMonth() == end.getMonth() && d > end.getDate())) {
      break;
    }
    year = (start.getMonth() == 0) ? start.getFullYear() - 1 : start.getFullYear();
    month = (start.getMonth() == 0) ? 12 : ("0" + start.getMonth()).slice(-2);
    day = ("0" + d).slice(-2);
    between.push(day + "." + month + "." + year);
    d++;
  }
  start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 1);

}
console.log(between);
```